# What are LB, HB, UB, and MB in hex data?

Tags: hex, byte

I have a question in the code below.

I know as follows.

```
Hex 00FC = Decimal 252.  (Note:  High byte(HB) is 00.  Low byte(LB) is FC.)  
Hex 0565 = Decimal 1381.  (Note:  High byte(HB) is 05.  Low Byte(LB) is 65.)
```

I have confirmed that there are additional UB, MB.

```
{

    UINT32 dwData;

    ...
    ...     


    dwData.Val = 0x00000101;

    ...
    ...

    //Write Bytes
    WriteByte(dwData.byte.LB);
    WriteByte(dwData.byte.HB);
    WriteByte(dwData.byte.UB);
    WriteByte(dwData.byte.MB);

    ...
    ... 

}
```

What are LB, HB, UB, and MB?

Comment: Not sure these are standard acronyms.  However, a quick Google search reveals that they are used by at least one embedded tools provider - https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=LB%2C+HB%2C+UB%2C+MB+byte.

Comment: `LB` and `HB` could be low/high bits. `UINT32` would use 4 bytes so your upper/lower byte logic works more for `UINT16`... Where are you getting the `UB` and `MB` confirmation from? Got a link of where this all came from _eg:_ Github or some tutorial? Also tag the correct programming language (here looks like `c++` or `c#`?).